# Setting width to field in Custom Manager

Tags: blackberry

I am very new to blackberry and trying to make one custom manager. So I am trying to make layout very simple which will show two Labelfields besides each other.(I can obtain this very easily by putting both of them to HorizontalFieldManager but I need to do this with custom manager.)

Out put should be like this :- `Hello(FirstField) User(SecondField)`

here is my sublayout method in my class which extend to Manager

```
public MyManager() {
    // construct a manager with vertical scrolling
    super(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
    }

protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        Field field;
        // get total number of fields within this manager
        int numberOfFields = getFieldCount();
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFields; i++) {
            field = getField(i); // get the field
            setPositionChild(field, x, y); // set the position for the field
            layoutChild(field, width, height); // lay out the field
            x = x + field.getHeight();
        }
        setExtent(width, height);
    }
```

If I remove this line `x = x+field.getWidth();` then both texts (Hello User) will be overlapped
(i think this is because of x,y = 0) now I desire that I will get `field.getWidth()` will return me width that is used by field one but instead it is giving me display's width(this is what I think) so I can see only Hello in my layout.

For positioning items vertically it works properly using `y = y+field,getHeight();` but don't know why `getWidth` is not returning me proper width value, may be possible that I mislead somewhere to understand this problem.

Do I need to override `getPrefferedWidth()` Method? I also tried this and leave this method as it is but then it just leave few spaces(2-3) between two fields and other texts overlapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I've added a full scale example that is based on your question and my answer before the update (I've taken the `sublayout()` method remained the same except for the missing `y` variable definition that I've added).

When you override sublayout, you should first layout your fields and only then position them.  Try this code:

```
public final class HelloUserScreen extends MainScreen {
    public HelloUserScreen() {        
        Manager customManager = new Manager(0) {
            protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
                Field field;
                int numberOfFields = getFieldCount();

                int widthUsed = 0;
                int maxHeight = 0;
                int y = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFields; i++) {
                    field = getField(i); // get the field

                    // first layout
                    layoutChild(field, width-widthUsed, height);

                    // then position
                    setPositionChild(field, widthUsed, y);

                    widthUsed += field.getWidth();
                    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, field.getHeight());
                }

                setExtent(widthUsed, maxHeight);
            }
        };

        LabelField helloLabel = new LabelField("Hello ");
        helloLabel.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN)); 
        customManager.add(helloLabel);

        LabelField userLabel = new LabelField("user");
        userLabel.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.YELLOW)); 
        customManager.add(userLabel);

        add(customManager);
    }
}
```

This code produces the following screen

[image]

You should take into account that after layouting some field, the available width and height left for layouting gets smaller (in your case, because you are layouting your fields horizontally, *mostly* the width matter).

Another thing is that you want to call the `setExtent()` method with the width and height you actually used for layouting your fields and not the maximum width and height received in `sublayout()` (unless you are doing it intentionally because of some specific UI layout logic).

Comment: I think y will be maxHeight here in setPositionChild method. I tried but It is showing me still only one element in whole screen.

Comment: @R.j. You only posted a portion of the code here. The definition of the fields is missing - post them. The behavior you describe can be caused by a field that uses all the available width given to it. In any case, as I said in my answer - you should layout the fields first and only than position them (otherwise, you will try to position them before their width and height are not determined yet).

Comment: Hi, I only override this method in my custom manager class and have one constructor which I have edited in my code.

Comment: @R.j. I've updated my answer. The `sublayout()` method remained the same. I've added few lines of code to show that the `sublayout()` method that I posted works as expected.

Comment: I think problem is something else keep your code same and try with RichTextField instead LabelField  then it will cover whole width(I do not know why).

Comment: @R.j. I am sorry but I'm not going to spend more time on this question until you update it and make it complete. You explicitly said that you are using `LabelField`s and now you are saying `RichTextField`s. `LabelField` is not `RichTextField` and that's exactly the reason why I asked you to post the definition of your fields previously.

Comment: I am really sorry for creating this confusion in LabelField and RichTextField, actually I did not concentrate too much on these fields instead I was thinking about manager only and hoping no matter which Field I take(LabelField/RichTextField) as I am using my custom manager I will set these fields height and width through manager itself but I think I was wrong. Ok so in RIchtextField it takes all width right?

Comment: Right. As far as I can remember all class that subclass from `TextField` *automatically* consume all width passed to via the `layoutChild()` method. If you want to set a custom width, you can do so in `layoutChild()` method (for example layoutChild(someChild, 100, height)).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the custom field here. Use just `HorizontalFieldManager` and override `getPreferredWidth()` for the `Field` and `return getScreen().getWidth() / 2` there.

Comment: Hello Eugen, yes I can achieve this easily by Horizontal manager but I want to implement custom manager and I found this example very easy to implement and to know how I can achieve custom designing in blackberry so that is why I am doing it via extending manager class.